# Upload img with e.target.files[0] to url

Tags: reactjs, image, api, url, jsx

I want to upload img to api (any api such imgbb) to get url for img **BUT** I want upload when the user select img with input tag (onChange event) without save img locally ( with path )
I searched over net but cant any thing about this, any help ??

the img from input tag

```
const [image, setImage] = useState({ preview: "", raw: "" });
```

the handle chnage of input (upload img from user)

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files.length) {
      console.log(e.target.files);
      setImage({
        preview: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]),
        raw: e.target.files[0],
      });
    } else console.log("upload img");
  };
```

the jsx code that show input and button
the img preview

```
{image.preview ? (
              <img
                src={image.preview}
                alt="UserImg"
              />
            ) : (
              <>
                <h3 className="text-center">Upload your photo</h3>
              </>
            )}
```

the input

```
<input
            accept="image/*"
            id="upload-button"
            multiple
            type="file"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something sanity to build link

```
import myConfiguredSanityClient from '@sanity/client'
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url'

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(myConfiguredSanityClient)

const handleImage = (e) => {
const image_url = builder.image(e.target.files[0])
console.log("image_url",image_url.url())
 setimage(e.target.files[0])
 console.log("e.target.files[0]",e.target.files)
}
```